# How to use YUI calendar in Java Wicket?

Tags: java, yui, wicket

My question is not so hard, i think. But it does not change the fact that i dont know how to do it :) Anyway, how can i use yui calendar object in my wicket page? i have tried some codes in java codes, but i got some errors, so i need your precious help. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to do it? Could you describe, **more specifically**, **what** didn't work, and **how** it didn't work? Are you using Wicket Stuff?

Comment: I am simply trying to use yui calendar in my wicket page. i am using wicket stuff. if possible, i need for the working codes from who have tried this before.

Answer (score 8):

Its is as simple as this:

```
...
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.DateTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker;
...
DateTextField df = new DateTextField('wicketID', dateModel, "yy.DD.mm");
df.add(new DatePicker());
form.add(df);
```

Basicaly, you construct a normal DateTextField and add the YUI Picker to it. thats about all.

enjoy

Edit: to answer the questions in the comments:

user500129: are you using [maven](http://maven.apache.org) as build tool? i strongly suggest it to you. if you do, you find the yoi components in the wicket-datetime artefact. The relevant maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If you are not using maven, you can download the jar from the maven repository, for wicket.14.14 this would be the correct link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket-datetime/1.4.14

hope that helps

Comment: What is "datemodel" here? How can i get it? Thank you.

Comment: The `datemodel` is an object that implements `IModel<Date>`, and provides a place for Wicket to retrieve the original value and store the new value of the date field. You'll need to understand models to write a Wicket application.

Comment: ok, but i am still getting errors. i guess yui doesnt exist in my library. i searched internet and couldnt find a site to download it. does anybody know where can i download it? thank you so much.

Comment: Correct Adrian. i was refering to an IModel<Date> implementation. I thought that was clear to anyone using Wicket. @user500129: you realy should read something about Wickets core concepts..

Comment: is your question answered? if so, please mark the answer that helped to solve the problem.